# Firefox 67 browser.downloads.download(...) cookie data missing

Tags: firefox, cookies, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a small WebExtension for the firefox browser. 
Using browser.downloads.download(...) to trigger a download in Firefox 67 or above doesn't provide any cookie data anymore.

Basically the extension has the following code

```
browser.downloads.download({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/download.do',
    filename: 'path/to/file',
    conflictAction: 'uniquify'
}).then(id => {
    console.log(id);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Starting with Firefox 67 the request doesn't contain any cookie-Header anymore. No errors, no further informations. Everything works fine in Firefox 66 and below.
The documentation on MDN says:

> If the specified url uses the HTTP or HTTPS protocol, then the request
>   will include all cookies currently set for its hostname.

[See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download)

Any thoughts what changed or what I am missing?

Oh, and yes, I tried to set the cookie-Header by myself, leading to an error message: "Error: Forbidden request header name"

I already posted a report on [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1561654).

Comment: If you think it is a bug in Firefox, what do you expect here?

Comment: Anyone maybe experienced the same problem and found a workaround/solution.